# How can I calculate the weight a aero-spacecraft occupant experiences during sub-orbital but non-ballistic trajectories?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, sub-orbital, karman-line, tourism

Once in orbit, astronauts experience "weightlessness" relative to their capsule or space station because they are moving at the same orbital velocity as the surrounding spacecraft.

I have heard that the [SR-71 blackbird](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lockheed_SR-71_Blackbird) traveled above mach 3 which is about 14% of orbital velocity, and that it would therefore only experience 86% of the gravity of craft at rest.

Is this true?

This made me wonder what suborbital *but level* (non-ballistic) spaceflight would be like, where level means maintaining constant altitude.

**Question:** How can the weight a aero-spacecraft occupant experiences during sub-orbital but non-ballistic trajectories be calculated?

Comment: Your question does not seem to match the title. It's also unclear. Consider an edit. "Required" for what?

Comment: The SR-71's velocity and altitude are non-negligible in orbital mechanics, but are less than required for orbit. Hence "sub-orbital." I used it as an example of a sub-orbital trajectory because it might not be obvious to people who haven't played kerbal space program what I meant by it.

Comment: Your question doesn't seem to make any sense - even to folks who do play Kerbal. What are you actually asking? What do you mean by "only need to accelerate upwards 86%"?

Comment: Are you asking if the SR-71 flew at 100% of orbital velocity, would it be travelling at orbital velocity?

Comment: I believe OP means something like this: At 0 horizontal velocity, you need to provide 100% of your weight in upward force to maintain altitude. At orbital velocity, you need to provide 0% of your weight in upward force to maintain altitude. The question: At 14% of orbital velocity, do you only need to provide 100%-14% = 86% of your weight in upward force to maintain altitude, or is the calculation different?

Comment: @RussellBorogove what's your interpretation of "craft at rest"?

Comment: [Upward force required to] maintain altitude at zero horizontal velocity.

Comment: Ah. So if one substitutes "force" for "acceleration", one could get your interpretation.

Comment: Ugh, I have everything but the final answer, because today is not a trig day.

Comment: @RussellBorogove throw in the Karman line to make it absolutely perfect.

Comment: Yeah sorry about that! @RussellBorogove interpreted what I was asking correctly.

Comment: Once in a while I'll make a big edit to a new user's question in order to 1) help reopen it, and 2) help them see how to ask a question that fits better with the site's style. I've added more "science words" and "space words" in order to help get the question **reopened.** I've also tried to be careful not to change the question enough that it impacts the answer(s) that have been already posted. Personally I think **insta-closing** was *unhelpful, unproductive and untoward here*; there was no reason to **pre-block answers** so quickly.

Comment: @uhoh: Nice edit, voting to reopen.

Comment: I feel like the edit may have gone a little far; it now reads almost like a subjective question of astronaut experience rather than a question about the mechanics/physics of an SR-71.

Comment: @RussellBorogove I think that the title is objective enough, and the "this" in the last sentence refers to "the weight a aero-spacecraft occupant 'feels' during sub-orbital but non-ballistic trajectories" I've reiterated the question from the title again within the body of the question, and changed "feels" to "experiences". How does it look now?

Comment: Original question didn't refer to occupants at all, but this is fine.

Comment: @uhoh I'm really sorry about the original question! Don't know a whole lot about this subject and I'm not good at making my questions understandable. This edit gets at what I was asking perfectly. 

Also, I think I figured out the answer myself! It's just the gravity at that distance from the center minus the centripetal force you would feel using the velocity and distance from the center. This would only work for level flight, but that's fine given the question I was asking. I also now have a cool way to find the orbital speed (for a circular orbit) at a given altitude!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My interpretation of your question is this:

- At 0 horizontal velocity, an aircraft needs to provide 100% of its weight in upward force to maintain its altitude.
- At orbital velocity, with the surface of the Earth curving away
  exactly as fast as the aircraft falls, it needs to provide 0% of is
  weight in upward force to maintain altitude.
- The question: For an aircraft traveling at 14% of
  orbital velocity, does it only need to provide 100%-14% = 86% of its
  weight in upward force to maintain its altitude, or is the calculation
  different?

If this interpretation is good, please consider editing your question to clarify.

> I heard that the SR-71 traveled at about 14% of orbital velocity,

Earth orbital velocity is ~7700 m/s; 14% would be 1080 m/s, or ~2410 mph. Wikipedia tells me the SR-71's maximum speed is 2200 mph; close enough.

> It would only need to accelerate upwards 86% of craft at rest.

At orbital velocity, the downward curvature of the Earth as you go forward exactly matches your falling speed, so that you don't need to accelerate upwards to maintain altitude. However, it's *not* a linear relationship.

[Centripetal acceleration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centripetal_force) is the inward acceleration needed to maintain a circular path, and the formula for it is $v^2 / r$. When $v$ is $v_{orbit}$ (orbital velocity for any given altitude), then by definition the acceleration is the same as $g$, the acceleration under Earth's gravity. When $v$ is below orbital velocity, $g$ is too large, so you need to cancel some of it out with upward acceleration, i.e. lift some of your own weight. At $v$ = ${0.14} \times {v_{orbit}}$, you'd want to accelerate downward at ${0.0196} \times {g}$ to maintain a circular path, so you need to cancel all but that much of the natural gravitational fall, and still lift 98% of your weight.

Comment: Wouldn't the upward acceleration be v^2/r? So for an SR-71 at 26 K meters (+ Earth radius) and that speed, ~.2 m/s^2 which is ~ 2% of g, pretty close to what you got.

Comment: Yeah, that seems reasonable.

Comment: I've edited the question and commented there and voted to re-open. I don't think that the edit makes any changes that affect your answer. If it does, please feel free to yell at me and/or edit it further. Also, is [centripetal acceleration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centripetal_force) $v^2/r$ all that's needed here? It's non-linear, zero at zero and $g$ at orbital speed and radius.

Comment: @uhoh I certainly thought so when I commented that 4 hours before you did.

Comment: @OrganicMarble I was focused on writing the "please feel free to yell at me" part. I'd come back a few minutes later to add the centripetal part but failed to scan for prior art. I saw "some sort of trigonometric relationship" here and under the question, got worried, and wanted to offer a simpler alternative. Now, did somebody say something about a deadline (excuses themself and leaves the room)

Comment: Fixed my cosine nonsense. The square relation seemed right to me at first, but then I outsmarted myself by thinking, "no, the arc of the Earth's surface is a circle, not a quadratic..." Thanks to you sensible people!

Comment: Huh! I had the exact same idea for how to figure out how much gravity would need to be canceled, and I was coming back here to resolve the question. Sorry about the confusing original question by the way. I'm only just learning f = ma in class and I'm not very good with formatting my questions in an understandable way. Thanks!